# Transformation of a term with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am failing to correctly factor out this term.  Assume that all parameters are greater than zero.

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
   p^2(L^{\alpha}\beta(\beta-1)K^{\beta-2}\cdot K^{\beta}\alpha(\alpha-1)L^{\alpha-2}-( \alpha L^{\alpha-1} \beta K^{\beta-1})^2) &> 0 \\[6pt]
\to\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\;(L^{\alpha}\beta(\beta-1)K^{\beta-2}\cdot K^{\beta}\alpha(\alpha-1)L^{\alpha-2}-( \alpha L^{\alpha-1} \beta K^{\beta-1})^2) &> 0 \\[6pt]
\to \quad(L^{\alpha}\beta(\beta-1)K^{\beta-2}\cdot K^{\beta}\alpha(\alpha-1)L^{\alpha-2}-(( \alpha L^{\alpha-1} \beta K^{\beta-1})( \alpha L^{\alpha-1} \beta K^{\beta-1})) &> 0 \\[6pt]
...??
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I have to end here:
\begin{equation}
\alpha \beta  (- \alpha - \beta +1 ) > 0
\end{equation}

Comment: You cannot simplify $ab(-a-b+1)$ anymore. What term do you want to simplify anyway?

Comment: It appears that you have a system of three inequalities and you are using $*$ to mean multiplication, is that correct?

Comment: @abiessu No, certainly not three inequalities. There are more inequalities $...??$ to come.

Comment: @DietrichBurde you're right, it's three lines of transformation so far.

Comment: What does $*$ mean in this context?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want to end there. From line 1 I have to end by ab(-a-b+1).

Comment: @abiessu sorry, just the normal multiplication. Sometimes I write it out, sometimes I leave it.

Comment: @Sueton Any further questions?

Comment: No, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sueton OK, you're welcome. Then it is a good idea to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the latin letters and omit $p^2$ to reduce the writing.

$$L^a\cdot b\cdot (b-1)\cdot K^{b-2}\cdot K^b\cdot a\cdot (a-1)\cdot L^{a-2}-(a\cdot L^{a-1}\cdot b\cdot  K^{b-1})^2$$

$$L^a\cdot b\cdot (b-1)\cdot K^{b-2}\cdot K^b\cdot a\cdot (a-1)\cdot L^{a-2}-a^2\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot b^2\cdot  K^{2b-2}$$

Factoring out $a\cdot b$

$$a\cdot b\left(L^a\cdot  (b-1)\cdot K^{b-2}\cdot K^b\cdot  (a-1)\cdot L^{a-2}-a\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot b\cdot  K^{2b-2}\right)$$

$$a\cdot b\left( (b-1)\cdot K^{b-2}\cdot K^b\cdot  (a-1)\cdot L^{2a-2}-a\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot b\cdot  K^{2b-2}\right)$$

Factoring out $L^{2a-2}$

$$L^{2a-2}\cdot a\cdot b\left( (b-1)\cdot K^{b-2}\cdot K^b\cdot  (a-1)-a\cdot  b\cdot  K^{2b-2}\right)$$

$$L^{2a-2}\cdot a\cdot b\left( (b-1)\cdot K^{2b-2}\cdot  (a-1)-a\cdot  b\cdot  K^{2b-2}\right)$$

Factoring out $K^{2b-2}$

$$K^{2b-2}\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot a\cdot b\left( (b-1)\cdot  (a-1)-a\cdot  b\right)$$

$$K^{2b-2}\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot a\cdot b\left( b\cdot a-b-a+1-a\cdot  b\right)$$

$$K^{2b-2}\cdot L^{2a-2}\cdot a\cdot b\left(-b-a+1\right)$$